# Find translation of point on grid using angle and distance of motion

Tags: math, graph

I am attempting to create an in-game projectile that moves on a grid at a certain translation per second, but to do this I need equations to find the translation of the projectile in the two orthogonal directions using the angle of motion and the distance per second (speed).

Comment: that's correct, yes

Comment: i have clarified it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the speed u into ux and uy using trigonometry.

[image]

```
S  = U * time;
Sx = S * cos ( theta )
Sy = S * sin ( theta )
```